# int and vector "was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++

This is my first post in SO. I am having trouble getting this to compile. It keeps saying that `journalKey` and `journalKeyCount` are not declared in this scope. It also says that my constructor, destructor, and all my functions are "redefinitions".

this is the .h

```
/** class journal
    Project 1.
    @file journal.h */

#ifndef JOURNAL_H
#define JOURNAL_H
#include <vector>

class journal
{
    private:
        char journalName;

    public:
        journal();
        virtual ~journal();

        int journalKeyCount = 0;
        vector<char> journalKey;

        void makeJournal(const char journalName); //Adds a journal to the journalKey vector
        void displayJournal(const int journalID); //Outputs the data of a journal
};

#include "journal.cpp"
#endif // JOURNAL_H
```

and this is the .cpp

```
/** class journal
    Project 1.
    @file journal.cpp */

using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include "journal.h"
#include <vector>

/**<
Default constructor.
*/
journal::journal()
{
}

/**<
Default deconstructor.
*/
journal::~journal()
{
}

/**<
Adds a journal to the journalKey vector.
@retuen void
@param journalName the name of the journal being added.
@pre -
@post The new journal name has been added to the end of the journalKey vector
*/
void makeJournal(const char journalName)
{
    journalKey.push_back(journalName);
    //journalKey[journalKeyCount] = journalName;
    journalKeyCount++;
}

/**<
Outputs the name of a journal that is set to the provided key.
@retuen void
@param journalID they ID key of the journal name.
@pre journalID key must exist.
@post -
*/
void displayJournal(const int journalID)
{
    if(journalID > journalKeyCount)
        cout << "Journal does not exist" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Journal Name: " << journalKey[journalID] << endl;
}
```

Thank you in advance for and advice.

**Updated**

.h

```
/** class journal
    Project 1.
    @file journal.h */

#ifndef JOURNAL_H
#define JOURNAL_H
#include <vector>

class journal
{
    private:
        char journalName;

    public:
        journal();
        virtual ~journal();

        int journalKeyCount = 0;
        vector<char> journalKey;

        void makeJournal(const char journalName); //Adds a journal to the journalKey vector
        void displayJournal(const int journalID); //Outputs the data of a journal
};

#endif // JOURNAL_H
```

.cpp

```
/**<
Default deconstructor.
*/
journal::~journal()
{
}

/**<
Adds a journal to the journalKey vector.
@retuen void
@param journalName the name of the journal being added.
@pre -
@post The new journal name has been added to the end of the journalKey vector
*/
void journal :: makeJournal(const char journalName)
{
    journalKey.push_back(journalName);
    //journalKey[journalKeyCount] = journalName;
    journalKeyCount++;
}

/**<
Outputs the name of a journal that is set to the provided key.
@retuen void
@param journalID they ID key of the journal name.
@pre journalID key must exist.
@post -
*/
void journal :: displayJournal(const int journalID)
{
    if(journalID > journalKeyCount)
        cout << "Journal does not exist" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Journal Name: " << journalKey[journalID] << endl;
}
```

error log is much shorter but im still getting:

```
warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]|
error: redefinition of 'journal::journal()'|
error: 'journal::journal()' previously defined here|
error: redefinition of 'journal::~journal()'|
error: 'virtual journal::~journal()' previously defined here|
error: redefinition of 'void journal::makeJournal(char)'|
error: 'void journal::makeJournal(char)' previously defined here|
error: redefinition of 'void journal::displayJournal(int)'|
error: 'void journal::displayJournal(int)' previously defined here|
```

You guys are fast and so helpful =D

Comment: You're including the cpp file at the end of the header file... think about that for a moment.

Comment: Add `journal::` before each function like with the constructors.

Comment: @EdS. "think about that for a moment" is less than helpful to a new programmer who is unfamiliar with the conventions of managing multiple translation units.

Comment: As a general rule, you should **never** `#include` a CPP file. This goes against the C++ conventions and can even defeat most of the benefits of organizing your code in separate CPP files.

Comment: If (with your help) fixed some of the code do I edit my original post or do I put the updated code in the answer section?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: You could be right. It depends on whether or not they know what happens when you `#include` a file.  I didn't mean it to be snarky.

Comment: @EdS. It's probably safer to assume that a new SO user **doesn't** know how #include works, even at a superficial level.

Comment: i know that '#include' includes a library or a file. I just remember being taught to include my .cpp at the bottom of my .h but it seems like that is a no no.

Comment: If I applied the suggested changes and it resolved some but not all of my errors do I post the updated code in an edit below the original code, overwrite the original code with the updated code or make a whole new question?

Comment: @Chalandria Make sure you're not #including `journal.cpp` anywhere. Also, you should probably include `journal.h` in `journal.cpp`.

Comment: @EdS. Well, to be fair, occasionally it does make sense to do that (not here though) although I'd suggest `.impl` or `.ipp` instead of `.cpp`.

Comment: @DavidYoung: It never makes sense to violate the one definition rule.

Comment: @EdS. It does if you want to separate template declarations from their definitions since there is no other way to do it.

Comment: I guess you could include the .cpp/.ipp file instead of the .h in the other parts of the code, but you'd still need to include that implementation file instead of the header file.

Comment: @DavidYoung: Which is not relevant here and is also a strange thing to do in and of itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When defining member functions outside their class you need to use a *nested name specifier*, or `journal::` to refer to the member function. You did this correctly for the constructor and destructor in the .cpp file, now you need to do it to `makeJournal` and `displayJournal` as well.

And as Ed S. said, it is wrong to include .cpp files in .h files. Rather, you *link* your source files together using your compiler.